# google map marker not able to see on map in IE browser

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

Problem getting to access  [this link](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_spin&chld=0.7|0|8e9e23|9|_|1)  in IE browser but able to access this link in other browser.So that the marker is not displaying. Please guide me how to access this site in IE so that the marker will be visible on map in visualforce page using IE browser.

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: What version of IE?  What does your code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the host `chart.googleapis.com` instead of `chart.apis.google.com`

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_spin&chld=0.7%7C0%7C8e9e23%7C9%7C_%7C1
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But actually I can't  change the code because it is in managed package. I want the way How can I access that link in IE  may be by setting.I don't know exactly..

Comment: send a bug-report to the developer of the package

Comment: I am the developer of that package. I have to give the solution to client.